# Can GeoProcessor use credentials?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, rest, wpf

I've set up a web service that uses ESRI's REST API spec. This allows me to make requests using the (Silverlight)/WPF SDK.  If I turn on windows authentication though,
I get a 401 error when using [GeoProcessor.ExecuteAsynch](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.Geoprocessor~ExecuteAsync.html).

I can successfully call the same url with a WebClient with credentials set:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
c.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

If I use WebClient, then I have to deserialize ESRI's json, which is non-trivial, so I'd really like to use Geoprocessor.ExecuteAsynch instead.

Is there some way to send credentials with Geoprocessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation: [Secure services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/Secure_services.htm)  it should be possible to secure the services. By using Token or windows credentials. On the base class TaskBase there is a Token and ProxyURL property for token based and Proxy based security. But I can't find any reference to exactly how to set the windows credentials. Only a statement that it is possible:

> There are two approaches to accessing
>   a secured service using HTTP/Windows
>   authentication:
>
> 1. Prompt the user to provide authentication credentials. Provide a
>      dialog in the Silverlight application
>      or use the browser to handle a
>      challenge response from a secure
>      service. The browser will provide a
>      standard authentication dialog to
>      enter a username and password. If
>      using HTTP Basic authnication all
>      communication with a service should be
>      handled over a secure connection
>      (HTTPS).